# Airflow webserver doesnt start except in debug mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, airflow

Airflow webserver start only in debug mode:

`airflow webserver -p 8051`

And the `traceback` I get:

```
[2016-12-07 03:38:48,056] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2016-12-07 03:38:48,056] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from  /home/user/some_dir/airflow/dags. Running the Gunicorn server with 4 syncworkers on host 0.0.0.0 and port 8051 with a timeout of 120... 
['gunicorn', '-w 4', '-k sync', '-t 120', '-b 0.0.0.0:8051', '-n airflow-  webserver', '-p /home/user/some_dir/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid', 'airflow.www.app:cached_app()']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./airflow", line 15, in <module> args.func(args)
File "/home/user/userenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 426, in webserver 'gunicorn', run_args
File "/home/user/userenv/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 344, in execvp
_execvpe(file, args) File "/home/user/userenv/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 380, in _execvpe func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
```

But `airflow webserver -p 8051 -d` works

Also I can't see `airflow-webserver.pid` file in `$AIRFLOW_HOME`

But in debug mode I can't run airflow worker

Answer (score 1):

It appears that gunicorn has not been installed properly or does not exist on the `PATH` that the airflow process is running under.

You didn't specify what version of Airflow you are running, but [here is an excerpt from the master branch that shows how running the webserver with and without the debug flag works](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L695).

Notice how running in debug mode starts a flask application. Running in normal mode runs the webserver on gunicorn. The `No such file or directory` exception likely indicates that airflow is attempting to run gunicorn but cannot find it on your `PATH`. To verify, try running `gunicorn` from a terminal in the same directory that you use to start the airflow process. You could also take a look at the `bin` directory of the python environment that you are using. If there is no `gunicorn` executable there, you've diagnosed your issue.

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the gunicorn package.

Comment: In my case, I had to upgrade gunicorn from 19.3 to 19.4 (the apparently required version for airflow 1.9). I'm not sure why the airflow webserver seemed to work fine when I had started it previously (days earlier). Anyway, the uninstall/reinstall (with upgrade) worked successfully for me.